# Table doesn't appear correctly

Tags: beamer

This is the problem:

```
! Undefined control sequence.  
<argument> ...~${\rm {2_1/a}}$ & 2,32 & \multirow   
                                              {2}{*}{\parbox {3cm}{színt...
l.596 \end{frame}    

The control sequence at the end of the top line  
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have  
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct  
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,  
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

(Thanks.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\mode<presentation> {  
\usetheme{Madrid}  
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}  
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] 
\newenvironment{reference}[2]{%  
  \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(#1,#2)  
  \footnotesize\it\bgroup\color{red!50!black}}{\egroup\end{textblock*}}
}

\usepackage[magyar]{babel}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{pbox}  
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{Észrevételek II.  \hspace{6.8cm} \small{Felhasználás}}  

\begin{center}  
\textcolor{blue}{3.táblázat}  
Oxalát tartalmú ásványok néhány jellemző tulajdonsága.  

\resizebox{10cm}{8cm}{  
\begin{tabular}{l l c c c c c p{3cm} c}  
\hline  
Ásvány neve & Kémiai összetétele & Kristályrendszer& Kristályosztály & Tércsoport & ${\rm {\rho_{meas}(g/mL)}}$ & Szín & Mohs\\  
\hline  
whewellit & ${\rm{Ca(C_2O_4)\cdot H_2O}}$ & monoklin & 2/m prizma & ${\rm{P2_1/n}}$ & 2,21-2,23 &\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{fehér, sárga, barna, színtelen}} & ${\rm{2\frac{1}{2}-3}}$  \\  [+0.4in]  
weddellit & ${\rm{Ca(C_2O_4)\cdot 2~ H_2O}}$  & tetragonális & 4/m dipiramis & |4/m & 1,94 & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{színtelen, fehér, sárgásbarnától barnáig}} & 4\\  [+0.4in]  
caoxit & ${\rm{Ca(C_2O_4)\cdot 3~H_2O}}$ & triklin & ${\rm{\overline{1}}}$ véglap & ${\rm P\overline{1}}$ & 1,85 & színtelen & ${\rm{2-2\frac{1}{2}}}$  \\ [+0.4in]  
nátroxalát & ${\rm{Na_2C_2O_4}}$ & monoklin & 2/m prizma & P~${\rm{2_1/a}}$ & 2,32 &  \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{színtelen, fehér, halványsárga}} & 3 \\ [+0.4in]  
novgorodovait & ${\rm{Ca_2(C_2O_4)Cl_2\cdot 2~ H_2O}}$ & monoklin & 2/m prizma & |2/m & 2,38 & színtelen & 2,5 \\ [+0.4in]  
\hline  
\end{tabular}  
}  
\end{center}  

\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: To be honest, that table is simply too big. It just fits a landscape letter page with modified margins. There is no way to reasonable put the data on a small beamer frame.

Comment: You have to `\usepackage{multirow}`, but there are several other errors in the code; for instance missing `$` signs.

Comment: YES, it is big, it can be smaller if \textcolor and the next lines are deleted.

Comment: I'd like show this table in one slide.I don't know where is this sign (     $  ) missed.

Comment: Not $ sign is the problem. I copied and modified the command line here badly. In the original file I have $ sign.I will correct in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't compile your code, it complains about encoding, but your code has an uneven number of `$`, 25 to be exact. This means that one couple is "open", so the rest of the document is in "math mode", including `\end{document}`.

In the first row you have `{\rm{P2_1/n}}$`, add a dollar sign at the beginning so it becomes `${\rm{P2_1/n}}$`.

Also, as egreg said in the comments, you need to add the package `\usepackage{multirow}` if you use the command in your table.

Comment: Thanks egreg and Alenanno. The multirow usepackage missed.

Comment: Just remember the backslash:  `\usepackage{multirow}`.  That was mistakenly left out in the answer.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii Ops, nice catch. Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- `\multirow` is completely unnecessary, there are too many `c`, thus that `p{3cm}` is not applied to this row. Removing one `c` fixes the issue without the need for a `\mutlirow`/`\parbox` construct.
- Chemical formulas can be set with the help of package `mhchem`.
- Numbers and units are covered by package `siunitx` with lots of configuration options.
- `\resizebox` switches to horizontal mode, thus the spaces before the tabular and after the tabular matters. They can be removed by commenting the line ends.
- `\resizebox{10cm}{8cm}` distorts the table, if the ratio of width and height is not 5 to 4 exactly. For example, `!` can be used for the height.
  Also `\linewidth` is better than the magic number for the width to fill the full line width.
- Package `booktabs` is loaded but it is not used. `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` makes nicer rules. Also `\addlinespace` sets a configurable additional space.
- The following example replaces the fractions in the last column by decimal numbers to avoid too tiny/unreadable digits.
- Of course, the table is quite hopelessly large. The distance between the columns can be reduced and the the table resized, but the audience will not recognize much at some distance.
- The magic number `6.8cm` in the title can be removed by a stronger `\hfill`. `\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}` (three `l`) moves the smaller word to the right. BTW, `\small` does not have an argument, its setting is valid until the end of the group.

The following example fixes some of the issues, especially columns 2, 5, 6, and 7:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Madrid}  
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  per-mode=symbol,
  range-phrase=--,
  output-decimal-marker={,},
}
%\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}  
\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{Észrevételek II. \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}{\small Felhasználás}}  

\begin{center}  
\textcolor{blue}{3. táblázat}  
Oxalát tartalmú ásványok néhány jellemző tulajdonsága.  

\medskip
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.5\tabcolsep}%
  \begin{tabular}{l l c c c c >{\RaggedRight}p{2.7cm} c}  
    \toprule
    Ásvány neve
    & Kémiai összetétele
    & Kristályrendszer
    & Kristályosztály
    & Tércsoport
    & $\rho_{\text{meas}}(\si{\gram\per\milli\liter})$
    & Szín
    & Mohs
    \\\midrule  
    whewellit
    & \ce{Ca(C2O4).H2O}
    & monoklin
    & 2/m prizma
    & P$2_1$/n
    & \numrange{2,21}{2,23}
    & fehér, sárga, barna, színtelen
    & \numrange{2,5}{3}
    \\\addlinespace
    weddellit
    & \ce{Ca(C2O4).2H2O}
    & tetragonális
    & 4/m dipiramis
    & |4/m
    & \num{1,94}
    & színtelen, fehér, sárgásbarnától barnáig
    & \num{4}
    \\\addlinespace
    caoxit
    & \ce{Ca(C2O4).3H2O}
    & triklin
    & $\bar 1$ véglap
    & P$\bar 1$
    & \num{1,85}
    & színtelen
    & \numrange{2}{2,5}
    \\\addlinespace 
    nátroxalát
    & \ce{Na2C2O4}
    & monoklin
    & 2/m prizma
    & P~$2_1$/a
    & \num{2,32}
    & színtelen, fehér, halványsárga
    & \num{3}
    \\\addlinespace  
    novgorodovait
    & \ce{Ca2(C2O4)Cl2.2H2O}
    & monoklin
    & 2/m prizma
    & |2/m
    & \num{2,38}
    & színtelen
    & \num{2,5}
    \\
    \bottomrule 
  \end{tabular}%  
}  
\end{center}  

\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I tried to correct the whole file but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user65789 Do you mean "correct" or "compile"? Without more details, "doesn't work" is quite a useless statement.

Comment: LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 49, version
               `2014/11/25' of package expl3,
               but only version
               `2014/09/15 v5423 L3 programming layer (loader) '
               is available.


! Package l3keys2e Error: Support package l3kernel too old.

See the l3keys2e package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                
l.61   }
Please install an up to date version of l3kernel
using your TeX package manager or from CTAN.
Loading l3keys2e will abort!

Comment: Continue:! Undefined control sequence.
l.7174 \NewDocumentCommand \DeclareBinaryPrefix
                                                { m m m } {
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.7205     \IfNoValueF {#
                         1}
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

Comment: ! siunitx error: "unknown-option"
! Unknown option '##1'.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.7206       { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
                                             }
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| The option file '##1' is not known by siunitx:perhaps it is spelled
| incorrectly.
|...............................................

Comment: And so on.      The end: ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: @user65789 Outdated packages. Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: [link] (http://www.mammutmail.com/hu/mail/download/e7c5c875f0fd7e6fe4743cd17df8c3fb)

Answer (score 0):

If the following changes are applied to your (updated) example:

- Add the instruction `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`,
- Add the instruction `\usepackage{multirow}`,
- Replace `\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, and
- Replace `\resizebox{10cm}{8cm}{` with `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{`

one gets:

[image]

Note the use of `!` as the second argument of `\resizebox`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\mode<presentation> {  
\usetheme{Madrid}  
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}  
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] 
\newenvironment{reference}[2]{%  
  \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(#1,#2)  
  \footnotesize\it\bgroup\color{red!50!black}}{\egroup\end{textblock*}}
}

\usepackage[magyar]{babel}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{pbox}  
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{Észrevételek II.  \hspace{6.8cm} \small{Felhasználás}}  

%\begin{center}  
\centering
\textcolor{blue}{3.táblázat}  
Oxalát tartalmú ásványok néhány jellemző tulajdonsága.  

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{  
\begin{tabular}{l l c c c c c p{3cm} c}  
\hline  
Ásvány neve & Kémiai összetétele & Kristályrendszer& Kristályosztály & Tércsoport & ${\rm {\rho_{meas}(g/mL)}}$ & Szín & Mohs\\  
\hline  
whewellit & ${\rm{Ca(C_2O_4)\cdot H_2O}}$ & monoklin & 2/m prizma & ${\rm{P2_1/n}}$ & 2,21-2,23 &\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{fehér, sárga, barna, színtelen}} & ${\rm{2\frac{1}{2}-3}}$  \\  [+0.4in]  
weddellit & ${\rm{Ca(C_2O_4)\cdot 2~ H_2O}}$  & tetragonális & 4/m dipiramis & |4/m & 1,94 & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{színtelen, fehér, sárgásbarnától barnáig}} & 4\\  [+0.4in]  
caoxit & ${\rm{Ca(C_2O_4)\cdot 3~H_2O}}$ & triklin & ${\rm{\overline{1}}}$ véglap & ${\rm P\overline{1}}$ & 1,85 & színtelen & ${\rm{2-2\frac{1}{2}}}$  \\ [+0.4in]  
nátroxalát & ${\rm{Na_2C_2O_4}}$ & monoklin & 2/m prizma & P~${\rm{2_1/a}}$ & 2,32 &  \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{színtelen, fehér, halványsárga}} & 3 \\ [+0.4in]  
novgorodovait & ${\rm{Ca_2(C_2O_4)Cl_2\cdot 2~ H_2O}}$ & monoklin & 2/m prizma & |2/m & 2,38 & színtelen & 2,5 \\ [+0.4in]  
\hline  
\end{tabular}  
}  
%\end{center}  

\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. \resizebox{.999\linewidth}{!}{ worked also.

Comment: It is impossible to replace \usepackage[latin2]{inputenc} with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} because the applied standard is ISO-8859-2.

Comment: @user65789 - `latin2` may well be the input encoding used by your text software. However, when you copy it to this website, it's automatically transformed to `utf8`. That's why I had to change the option passed to the `inputenc` package; without the change I couldn't complete compilation. As I said, your editor's settings may well be different.

Comment: @user65789 - Is there a meaningful difference between `1\linewidth` and `0.999\linewidth`?

Comment: I didn't find any differences (this previously mentioned command was on the Internet, I don't know what the numbers means exactly, I just used it).

Comment: @user65789 - I don't know what using `.999\linewidth` (instead of just `\linewidth`) may achieve other than provide clutter.